# Android: Quickest way to filter lists as user types a query

Tags: android, sorting, arraylist, filtering, comparator

Good day all, I have a list of Objects (Let's call them ContactObject for simplicity). This object contains 2 Strings, Name and Email.

This list of objects will number somewhere around 2000 in size. The goal here is to filter that list as the user types letters and display it on the screen (IE in a recyclerview) if they match. Ideally, It would filter where the objects with a not-null name would be above an object with a null name.

**As of right now, the steps I am taking are:**

**1)** Create 2 lists to start and get the String the user is typing to compare to

```
List<ContactObject> nameContactList = new ArrayList<>();
List<ContactObject> emailContactList = new ArrayList<>();
String compareTo; //Passed in as an argument
```

**2)** Loop though the master list of ContactObjects via an enhanced for loop

**3)** Get the name and email Strings

```
   String name = contactObject.getName();
   String email = contactObject.getEmail();
```

**4)** If the name matches, add it to the list. Intentionally skip this loop if the name is not null and it gets added to the list to prevent doubling.

```
     if(name != null){
        if(name.toLowerCase().contains(compareTo)){
            nameContactList.add(contactObject);
            continue;
        }
    }
    if(email != null){
        if(email.toLowerCase().contains(compareTo)){
            emailContactList.add(contactObject);
        }
    }
```

**5)** Outside of the for loop now as the object lists are build, use a comparator to sort the ones with names (I do not care about sorting the ones with emails at the moment)

```
Collections.sort(nameContactList, new Comparator<ContactObject>() {
            public int compare(ContactObject v1, ContactObject v2) {
                String fName1, fName2;
                try {
                    fName1 = v1.getName();
                    fName2 = v2.getName();
                    return fName1.compareTo(fName2);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return -1;
                }
            }
        });
```

**6)** Loop through the built lists (one sorted) and then add them to the master list that will be used to set into the adapter for the recyclerview:

```
for(ContactObject contactObject: nameContactList){
    masterList.add(contactObject);
}
for(ContactObject contactObject: emailContactList){
    masterList.add(contactObject);
}
```

**7)** And then we are all done.

Herein lies the problem, this code works just fine, but it is quite slow. When I am filtering through the list of 2000 in size, it can take 1-3 seconds each time the user types a letter.

My goal here is to emulate apps that allow you to search the contact list of the phone, but seem to always to it quicker than I am able to replicate.

Does anyone have any recommendations as to how I can speed this process up at all?

Is there some hidden Android secret I don't know of that only allows you to query a small section of the contacts in quicker succession?

Comment: If you know anything about (or ar interested in) RxJava, you could play with the filter() method http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/filter.html . I know it can be a bit hard if you don't know anything about it, but just pointing you in a possible and interesting direction.

Comment: @DanielOcampo Thanks for the tip! I will look into that right away.